# how to add global filter with inertia vue3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm using Inertia and Vue 3 with Laravel. I need to know how to add global filters.

I tried to use this [referrance](https://primitive.dev/blog/vue-3-global-filters/) but it didn't work.

**app.js**

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({el, app, props, plugin}) {
        return createApp({render: () => h(app, props)})
            .use(plugin)
            .mixin({methods: {route}})
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

Comment: Is `title` meant to be the filter? If not, please can you show what you "filter" you're trying to add.

Comment: @Rwd any filter i need to know the right way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the blog post you linked to (and the [Vue.js 3 migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html#global-filters)), filters have been removed in v3 of Vue.js. The suggestion in the migration guide is to add a global property.

You can do this in your example with the following:

```
createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({el, App, props, plugin}) {

        const app =  createApp({render: () => h(App, props)})
            .use(plugin)
            .mixin({methods: {route}});

        app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
            currency(value) {
                return '$' + new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(value)
            },
            // Put the rest of your filters here
        }

        app.mount(el);
    },
});
```

Please note that I've updated the `setup` property name from `app` to `App` as per the vue 3 [example in Intertia's documentation](https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup).

You could then use this "filter" in your code using the `$filters` property:

```
<p>{{ $filters.currency(amount) }}</p>
```